# How do I find the 20 most visited destinations from a data set using MapReduce program?

Tags: java, mapreduce

Travel sector dataset description:

```
Column 1: City pair (Combination of from and to): String  
Column 2: From location: String  
Column 3: To Location: String  
Column 4: Product type: Integer (1=Air, 2=Car, 3 =Air + Car, 4 =Hotel, 5=Air + Hotel, 6=Hotel + Car, 7 =Air +
Hotel + Car)  
Column 5: Adults Traveling: Integer  
Column 6: Seniors traveling: Integer  
Column 7: Children traveling: Integer  
Column 8: Youth traveling: Integer  
Column 9: Infant traveling: Integer  
Column 10: Air booking price: Float  
Column 11: Car booking price: Float  
Column 12: Hotel booking price: Float  
Column 13: Airline code: String  
Column 14: Airline name: String  
Column 15: Car vendor code: String  
Column 16: Hotel name: String
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run two MR jobs:
`job1 map`: emits `["To",1]`
`job1 reduce`: finds count per destination and outputs `["To", count]`
`job2 map`: emits the output of previous job (as `[count, "To"]` or `["To", count]`)
`job2 reduce` (number of reducers=1): sorts and outputs 20 rows with largest values of `count`

For query tasks like this one, it is preferable to use an SQL-like query engine similar to Apache Hive. Hive will convert the query to 2 Map-Reduce jobs specified above.

Comment: I feel like Pig would require less work than Hive, as it is easier to setup

Comment: @cricket_007 that's possible, I never used Pig so it's hard for me to judge: )

Comment: As far as SQL goes, Drill is also somewhat simpler than Hive

Comment: Is it possible to perform two mapreduce tasks in a single program code.? I am new to mapreduce and what I am only understanding from your explaination is to use the output file which got created from my first mapReduce job as input to the next Job which means anothere output file will be created as final output. Is that so?

Comment: @KritikaRai the number of output files from your first map-reduce job will depend on the number of reducers that you will set to that job. of course you can implement the functionality of both reducers in the same reducer but keep in mind that you need to run second job (i.e. sorting) by one reducer only, so in case if your input data is large, you'll still need to run 2 jobs and set a suffiently large number of reducers for the first job

Comment: @mangusta Thanks for suggestion. I tried doing that. Nut what I found is sorting is done in ascending order. So instead of showing top 20 if showed the least visited once. Now I am unable to figure out how do I do sorting in descending order.

Comment: @KritikaRai if you sort in ascending order, the last 20 elements of a sorted list will be your answer

Comment: apparently i was wrong while stating about the possibility of implementing the functionality of destination count and sorting in the same reducer. 
i think that's impossible because the key-value pair is different for both: for the first job, reducer takes <key=destination, value=list of counts coming from mappers or other reducers> and for the sorting, reducer takes something like <key=" ",  value=list of destinations together with their counts>